NASM ORG doesn't like SECTION
Looks like NASM ORG directive doesn't behave correctly in the presence of SECTION directive, in spite that it's compiled to the binary format. I wonder if there's an alternative for ORG in NASM which behave well when used together with SECTION and doesn't reserve a space in the output file?
Here are the related statements:
; some mbr code
; ....

[SECTION loader VSTART=0]
; some code, data and constants
; ....

ALIGN 512

SECTALIGN OFF
[SECTION intermediate_pm VSTART=0]
; some code, data and constants
; ....

SECTALIGN OFF
[SECTION kernel VSTART=0]
ORG 0x4000

kernel_start:
; some code, data and constants
; ....

ALIGN 512

I expect kernel_start to be equal to 0x4000 everywhere in the code. But if I use it in the "loader" or "intermediate_pm" section, it's equal to 0. The same is true if I use VSTART=0x4000 instead of ORG 0x4000.

Show exact test case please. I do use both org and section directives sometimes. However, in the -f bin flat binary output format (default if no -f switch given) you can use section attributes start= and vstart= to fulfill the same role as org (and more).

SECTION kernel VSTART=0x4000 leads to "kernel_start" not relocating to 0x4000 ?

@ecm Looks like I was fooled by the nasm listing. I tried different options and debugged not every of them. I debugged ORG 0x4000 and found that mov esi, kernel_start translates to mov esi, 0. But I checked VSTART = 0x4000 only in the .lst file and found that the same assembler code translates to BE[00000000]. Your question encouraged me to double check it with the debugger and I found that VSTART actually works. Thanks a lot!

Yeah, the -f bin format of NASM is said to involve a "linker internal to NASM" which is why some relocations will be processed not by the assembler proper but rather the linker. So you get a [00000000] style relocation marker in the listing file because the listing part doesn't communicate with the linker. I mentioned some of this in yesterday's blog post: https://pushbx.org/ecm/dokuwiki/blog/pushbx/2024/0714_early_mid_july_work
